# Attach class to div child with a delay (javascript or css) animation

Tags: javascript, css-animations

So I have this kind of structure, where every div child(.cc-entry-animation-colour) inside the container cc-entry-animation-wrapper have a different colour background, so I have a class animation that calls a keyframe and I would like to attach that class to the div child (.cc-entry-animation-colour) but not at the same time, so from top to down, with a delay of one second maybe.

```
<div class="entry-animation">
  <div class="cc-entry-animation-wrapper">

    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour green-3"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour green-2"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour green-1"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour blue-3"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour blue-2"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour blue-1"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour violet-3"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour violet-2"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour violet-1"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour red-3"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour red-2"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour red-1"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour orange-3"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour orange-2"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour orange-1"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour yellow-3"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour yellow-2"></div>
    <div class="cc-entry-animation-colour yellow-1"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

So this is the class looks:

```
.animate-fan{
    animation:abanico 2s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes abanico {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-90deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
  
    to {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
  }
```

I also tried already to achieve this with pure css, so I was applying the same animation to the different div class, but with a delay, see example below.

```
 .cc-entry-animation-colour.yellow-1 {
 /*more attributes here that I am omiting*/
        animation:abanico 2s infinite;
      }

 .cc-entry-animation-colour.yellow-2 {
      /*more attributes here that I am omiting*/
        animation:abanico 2s infinite;
      animation-delay:1s;
      }
 .cc-entry-animation-colour.yellow-3 {
      /*more attributes here that I am omiting*/
        animation:abanico 2s infinite;
      animation-delay:2s;
      }

...etc
```

But did not work properly, somehow is ignoring my delay in some and I only can see the first 3 divs get animated for some reason. So I'm trying to achieve a kind of "fan effect" by rotating the divs in a 90 angle, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the best practice but I suggest you to do like my example bellow :

1. Get all childs by using `children` property of `querySelectorAll`  result
2. For Each child apply the style `animationDelay` (you need increment by one second so you can use `index` to give you the correct value to apply)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const childs = [...document.querySelectorAll('cc-entry-animation-wrapper').children];

  childs.forEach(function(child, index) {
    child.style.animationDelay = `${index}s`;
  }
});
```

Or you can create some class who contains your delay :

```html
<style>
.delay-0 { animation-delay: 0s; }
.delay-1 { animation-delay: 1s; }
.delay-2 { animation-delay: 2s; }
.delay-3 { animation-delay: 3s; }
</style>

<!-- ... -->

<div class="cc-entry-animation-colour yellow-1 delay-0"></div>
```

this one can work dynamically, by playing with `classList` in javascript and statically like in my example.